# Why Sagepay notification reaches some of our servers but not the others

Tags: opayo

Currently we have a few test servers which connect to test.sagepay.com to process transactions. However, on 2 of the servers, we could successfully register transactions on sagepay, but then we didn't receive any sagepay notification coming back at all. However, on different servers (running on different IP addresses), it is working perfectly fine.

I've got the error code "5006 - Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL". It used to work perfectly fine on those servers, and only stopped working since last Thursday although we are sure that we didn't touch those servers during that period of time at all. Besides, we do see a few occasional notifications coming in from sage which we believe are the REPEAT notifications, not the original ones. We could see all those transactions registered on our accounts, but of course all of them are failed due to the fact that we haven't got any notification coming back.

And we also do make sure that our firewall is opened for the whole range 195.170.169.* from which we expect to receive the sage notification

So my questions are:

1. Does Sagepay have some sort of mechanism to block some IP addresses and stop sending back notification?
2. Is the Sagepay-serer which sends out original notifications different from the one that sends out Repeat notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the very same issue. Our script was handing https:// address over to SagePay as a NotificationURL, but https was not setup, hence the notification script could not be reached. Once I changed to http and ensured that the notification script response is correct it worked.

Also it seems that when SagePay could not reach RedirectURL it tried 8 more times.

I'm not exactly answering your questions, but perhaps it will help. I'd add this as a comment, but I can't...